# In q, how to add a symbol to a symbol

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to `load` a table with a variable name.

Let's say:

```
a:`partofurl;
```

Then this doesn't work:

```
load `:c:/q/a/table;
```

So how can I use the variable `a` in the url `symbol` expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain scenarios like this one you can use sv (http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#sv)

```
q)` sv `:c:/q,a,`table
`:c:/q/partofurl/table
```

Failing that, you can always string and append

```
q)`$":c:/q/",string[a],"/table"
`:c:/q/partofurl/table
```

Comment: Is that **the** way of doing this?

Comment: yes, `sv` is **the** way of doing this - this particular form of `sv` is provided to assist in building file paths (reference doc:  http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/sv)